# Is there a way to open and edit a visual Studio 2017 Solution on a remote Device?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, remote-access

I'm trying to open and edit a Visual Studio 2017 solution from a remote Computer to which I have a TCP/IP Connection. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Er. Share the source folder over SMB? Remote in via RDP or SSH?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019) have detailed steps about Remote Debugging. You could refer to it.